# Hex value from sql select

Tags: mysql

When i run select hex(col1) from table1; i get the result as hex number

for ex: the hex(65) is 41, but i wish to get directly thro sql query the result as 0x41 instead of 41, is there a way to get the result as 0x41?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select '0x' + hex(col1) from table1
```

**Update:**

I misread the tag and answered with the `+` operator as used in for MS-SQL. As Sharpeye says in the comment,

```
select concat('0x',hex(col1)) from table1
```

is the MySQL version.

Comment: Thanks Blair & i am a big fan of this stack overflow site, better than google. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat('0x',("65",'hex')) to query the result as 0x41 .